# For Each using Gridviews

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

So I've been working on this project for a while now and I'm stuck on one datagrid and I think I'm over thinking it.  I need to search my oracle db for a drug id, then do a foreach loop to pull the time it was administered out of the database using that drug ID and append it to a new column. Here is what I have so far:

```
// CONNECT TO THE ORACLE DATABASE
HCconn.ConnectionString = HCtest;
HCconn.Open();

// BUILD SQL COMMAND
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(queryString, HCconn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@visitNo",visitno);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

// POPULATE GRIDVIEW
GridView_inpatientRx.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OracleDataAdapter oAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
oAdapter.Fill(ds);
GridView_inpatientRx.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridView_inpatientRx.DataBind();


foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView_inpatientRx.Rows)
{
  // HERE IS WHERE I'M STUCK
}
```

I could use some guidance on where to move on from here.

Comment: Why do you want to add it to a column on the GridView? Why don't you just run a separate query to get the value and then put it in a label or textbox?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "append it to a new column"? Could you describe the database schema (tables/columns) as well?

Comment: row["columnName"] maybe this will get you started.

Comment: Why are you looping through the GridView instead of looping through the data?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I'm just trying to pull the very last entry of each dose given.  The problem I'm running in to is when I add the time administered to the search I gain multiple records for each drug.  The unique ID here is in the drug table, which is what links the time administered table.  I need to search the drug table for the drug name and the time administered table for the last time given for each record.  I was thinking pull the drug ID, then loop that table into searching the database for time given and then just appending each result to a new column in the datagrid.  Makes sense in my mind but idk.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can extract data from the GridView on your loop example as:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView_inpatientRx.Rows)
    {
        // and now read the content 
        row.Cells[NumberOfCell].Text
    }
```

Comment: I'm not following the "row.Cells[numberofcell].text" line.  How would I use that to run a second query using the first row of results from the datagrid as my variables?

Comment: @MattP I am direct answer the question. Beside that if you try to make something different than the question is your call. Now to run a second query, this have nothing to do with grid view, you make a query and run it, get the results etc... I do not know what to tell you on that, many tutorials on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a join in the SQL query you are constructing if possible.

`select d.drugid, d.drugname, p.patientName, dose.lastAdmistered from drug d
inner join dose dose on d.drugid=dose.drugid
inner join patient p on p.patientId = dose.patientId`

If not possible, then I would look into the [RowsAdded Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded(v=vs.110).aspx).

I don't have a winforms project up right now, but you would want to bind your grid and then do your lookup upon each rowadded event call (The query option would be much more efficient though).

Comment: The problem I'm having with doing it strait through SQL is it's adding duplicates in the datagrid since there were previous entries with the same drug_id.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you look into an ORM such as [Entity Framework](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/). With something like Entity Framework you can have it generate a strongly-typed model based off of your existing database, so you're not left manipulating row objects.